# Select meta_key value from WordPress DB tabel

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to write a SQL statement to get all of the email addresses from a WordPress DB from users within the US. Disclaimer, I have never written a SQL statement on my own. I've only modified other SQL statements. While this would be a simple SQL statement if the email and country were in separate columns of one DB table, they are stored in key/value pairs. I've attached a screenshot to illustrate. I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

I tried

```
SELECT meta_key.billing_email FROM `wp_xk_usermeta` WHERE meta_key.billing_country = "US";
```

I was hoping to get a list of all emails from people in the US.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of `show create table wp_xk_usermeta;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following data in `wp_xk_usermeta` -

| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | billing_email | joe.bloggs@example.com |
| 2 | 1 | billing_country | US |
| 3 | 2 | billing_email | jane.bloggs@example.com |
| 4 | 2 | billing_country | US |
| 5 | 3 | billing_email | dave.bloggs@example.com |
| 6 | 3 | billing_country | UK |

the following query -

```
SELECT `um1`.`meta_value` `billing_email`
FROM `wp_xk_usermeta` `um1`
JOIN `wp_xk_usermeta` `um2`
    ON `um2`.`user_id` = `um1`.`user_id`
    AND `um2`.`meta_key` = 'billing_country'
    AND `um2`.`meta_value` = 'US'
WHERE `um1`.`meta_key` = 'billing_email';
```

will return -

| billing_email |
| --- |
| joe.bloggs@example.com |
| jane.bloggs@example.com |

Comment: Thank you! This worked. What is `um1` and `um2`? Are those just variable names you gave them? I'm just trying to understand the statement so I can learn.

Comment: `um1` and `um2` are [table aliases](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/#:~:text=MySQL%20alias%20for%20tables) for `wp_xk_usermeta`. Tables are required to be uniquely identifiable in a query, otherwise the server would have no way of knowing which instance of the table we are referring to. Please remember to accept one of the answers if it answered your question.